# Swagger 2.0 updating the model returns default values instead of updated values in Ruby client side code

Tags: swagger-2.0

I'm using Swagger 2.0 and generating a Ruby client.

The issue I'm running into involves updating an object. The values being returned on the PATCH request are all the default values in the definition. For example, I have a default name of "Unnamed" and I run my patch script to update the name to "Marty", the response gives me back all my defaults in my definition, including "Unnamed". Peeking into the database does allow me to see that the params have all been appropriately updated, however.

Here's my YAML for the PATCH request and definition of Source, which is the object I'm updating:

```
patch:
  tags:
  - sources
  summary: Updates a source
  description: Updates a source by id
  operationId: patchASource
  consumes:
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  produces:
  - application/json
  - application/xml
  parameters:
  - name: id
    in: path
    description: ID of source that needs to be updated
    required: true
    type: integer
    format: int64
  - name: category
    in: formData
    description: Updated category of the source
    required: false
    type: integer
  - name: code
    in: formData
    description: Updated code of the source
    required: false
    type: integer
  - name: description
    in: formData
    description: Updated description of the source
    required: false
    type: string
  - name: file_name
    in: formData
    description: Updated file_name of the source
    required: false
    type: string
  - name: name
    in: formData
    description: Updated name of the source
    required: false
    type: string
  responses:
    200:
      description: Updated Source Successfully
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Source'
```

My Source Definition:

```
definitions:
  Source:
    properties:
      category:
        type: integer
        default: 0
        example: 0
        format: int32
      code:
        type: integer
        default: 0
        example: 201
        format: int32
      description:
        type: string
        default: ~
        example: "example description"
      file_name:
        type: string
        default: ~
        example: "iris.csv"
      name:
        type: string
        default: "Unnamed Source"
        example: "Iris Data"
```

So when I run my script to update the Source object, what I am getting returned in the response is all the default values in definition above. I can get the Source by id and see that it has in fact been updated.

Is there something wrong with the YAML that needs correcting to return the updated values in the response?

Please be kind as this is my first question on SO. :)